# How to edit span content with a onclick button function

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple to-do application in Javascript. The user can enter a new todo list item.
I also want the user to be able to edit an existing to-do item.

So I'm trying to make a button with a onClick function to edit a span.
But it keeps returning a **"span is null"** error.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code so far:

```js
function addToDo() {
    let input = document.getElementById("input").value + " ";
    var list = document.getElementById("list1");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var doneButton = document.createElement("button");
    doneButton.innerHTML = "Done";
    doneButton.onclick = moveToDo;
    doneButton.className = "move";
    var editButton = document.createElement("button");
    editButton.innerHTML = "Edit";
    editButton.onclick = editToDo;
    editButton.className = "edit";
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
    deleteButton.onclick = deleteToDo;
    deleteButton.className = "delete";
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = input;
    span.className = "node";
    li.appendChild(span);
    li.appendChild(doneButton);
    li.appendChild(editButton);
    li.appendChild(deleteButton);
    list.appendChild(li);
}

function moveToDo(x) {
    x.preventDefault();
    var button = x.target;
    var li = button.closest("li");
    button.remove();
    document.getElementById("list2").append(li);
}

function editToDo(b) {
    b.preventDefault();
    var button = b.target;
    var span = button.closest('span');
    var edit = prompt("Edit to-do item:");
    span.appendChild(edit);
}

function deleteToDo(x) {
    x.preventDefault();
    var button = x.target;
    var li = button.closest("li");
    li.remove();
}
```

```html
<title>emil avara &nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp; inlämningsuppgift 2</title>

<h1 class="center">BIG BOI TO DO LIST APPLICATION</h1>
<!-- <a href=""><span id="reset" onclick="window.location.reload();"></span></a> -->
<div id="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add a to-do"></input>
  <button id="add-button" onclick="addToDo()">Add</button>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="list1-div">
    <h1>TO-DO</h1>
    <ul id="list1">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="list2-div">
    <h1>DONE</h1>
    <ul id="list2">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives console errors

Comment: i didn't include all code, edited it now.
everything is functioning now, except the edit button.

Comment: See updated answer. I made a more elegant version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- closest does not work on siblings
- append needs a node. You have a string

This will work better

```
    var span = button.closest('li').querySelector('span');
    var edit = prompt("Edit to-do node:");
    span.textContent = edit;
```

```js
function moveToDo() {}
function deleteToDo() {}
function addToDo() {
  let input = document.getElementById("input").value + " ";
  var list = document.getElementById("list1");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var doneButton = document.createElement("button");
  doneButton.innerHTML = "Done";
  doneButton.onclick = moveToDo;
  doneButton.className = "move";
  var editButton = document.createElement("button");
  editButton.innerHTML = "Edit";
  editButton.onclick = editToDo;
  editButton.className = "edit";
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
  deleteButton.onclick = deleteToDo;
  deleteButton.className = "delete";
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.textContent = input;
  span.className = "node";
  li.appendChild(span);
  li.appendChild(doneButton);
  li.appendChild(editButton);
  li.appendChild(deleteButton);
  list.appendChild(li);
}

function editToDo(b) {
  b.preventDefault();
  var button = b.target;
  var span = button.closest('li').querySelector('span');
  var edit = prompt("Edit to-do node:");
  span.textContent = edit;
}
```

```html
<title>emil avara &nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp; inlämningsuppgift 2</title>

<h1 class="center">BIG BOI TO DO LIST APPLICATION</h1>
<!-- <a href=""><span id="reset" onclick="window.location.reload();"></span></a> -->
<div id="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add a to-do"></input>
  <button id="add-button" onclick="addToDo()">Add</button>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="list1-div">
    <h1>TO-DO</h1>
    <ul id="list1">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="list2-div">
    <h1>DONE</h1>
    <ul id="list2">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a more elegant version inspired by Mister Jojo's refactoring but with my own preferences

- made the buttons type="button" and added class btn
- delegated using the btn class
- used a template instead of createElement

```js
// buttons of type="button" do not need e.preventDefault();

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const list1 = document.getElementById("list1")
  const list2 = document.getElementById("list2")
  document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (!tgt.classList.contains("btn")) return; // not a button
    const li = tgt.closest("li");
    if (tgt.classList.contains("move")) {
      tgt.remove();
      list2.append(li);
    } else if (tgt.classList.contains("edit")) {
      const span = li.querySelector('span');
      const edit = prompt("Edit to-do node:", span.textContent); // allow modification of existing text
      span.textContent = edit;
    } else if (tgt.classList.contains("delete")) {
      li.remove();
    }
  });

  document.getElementById("add-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    let input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    let li = document.getElementById("liTemplate").content.cloneNode(true)
    if (input) {
      li.querySelector("span").textContent = input;
      list1.appendChild(li);
    }  
  })

})
```

```html
<title>emil avara &nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp; inlämningsuppgift 2</title>

<h1 class="center">BIG BOI TO DO LIST APPLICATION</h1>
<div id="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add a to-do" />
  <button type="button" id="add-button">Add</button>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="list1-div">
    <h1>TO-DO</h1>
    <ul id="list1">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="list2-div">
    <h1>DONE</h1>
    <ul id="list2">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="liTemplate">
<li>
  <span class="node"></span>
  <button type="button" class="move btn">Done</button>
  <button type="button" class="edit btn">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="delete btn">Delete</button>
</li>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `button.closest('span')` to select the `span` element. `closest()` traverses the element's ancestors, not its siblings. In your current code, edit button and span elements are within same parent node, so result of `closest()` should be always null.

Answer (score 0):

Because closest couldn't find span selector. The reason is .closest() find only parents selectors. If button.closest('ul') or button.closest('li') will get the element. You should use other method to select a span.

Answer (score 0):

the time to redo this code **mplungjan** had responded.
But since I made many improvements ...

```js
const DomParser = new DOMParser()
  ,   eInput    = document.getElementById('input')
  ,   list_s    = document.querySelector('div#wrapper')
  ,   todoList  = document.querySelector('ul#list1')
  ,   doneList  = document.querySelector('ul#list2')
  ;
function addToDo() 
  {
  let newLI = `
    <li>
      <span class="node">${eInput.value} </span>
      <button class="move"   data-op="done"   > Done </button>
      <button class="edit"   data-op="edit"   > Edit </button>
      <button class="delete" data-op="delete" > Delete </button>
    </li>`;
  todoList.appendChild(  (DomParser.parseFromString( newLI, 'text/html')).body.firstChild );
  }
list_s.onclick = e =>  // use event delegation for All buttons
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button[data-op]')) return  // reject others click on area
  let li = e.target.closest('li')
  switch (e.target.dataset.op)
    {
    case 'done':
      e.target.remove()
      doneList.append(li);
      break;
    case 'edit':
      let span  = li.querySelector('span')
        , txt   = prompt('Edit to-do item:', span.textContent)
        ;
      if (txt != null)  // cancel
        span.textContent =  txt
      break;
    case 'delete':
      li.remove()
      break;
    }
  }
```

```css
div#wrapper span 
  { 
  display       : inline-block;
  width         : 12em;
  border-bottom : 1px solid lightgray;
  }
```

```html
<h1 class="center">BIG BOI TO DO LIST APPLICATION</h1>
 
<div id="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add a to-do"></input>
  <button id="add-button" onclick="addToDo()">Add</button>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="list1-div">
    <h1>TO-DO</h1>
    <ul id="list1">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="list2-div">
    <h1>DONE</h1>
    <ul id="list2">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

recognize that it is still more readable!  ;)

Comment: Hmm, possibly above OP's head... I do not like your switch. It relies on each item having only one classname. I prefer if's: `if (tgt.classList.contains("edit")) ...; else if (tgt.classList.contains("delete"))` - even easier to read without the breaks and cases

Comment: And your DomParser code is really hard to read compared to innerHTML += liString

Comment: @mplungjan the template/clone is not a bad idea, I've used this technique before, but I finished to have too many elements (for different things) and I prefer to have the inserts codes directly visible in the JS codes

Comment: @mplungjan this is just a joke, and I upvoted your post ;) (and I'm also happy to have inspired you, good for my carma I suppose?)